# Neuronal network model Pseudo label

Tags: deep-learning

I am trying to classify two types of microscopic images, one class containing an object inside a cell, the other class with an empty cell.  I have about 30000 images and I tried already many different things including an own model of the images. However I received the best accuracy with feature extraction of the imagnet model and using a simple classifier to classify my images.

Now I got an idea, I do have millions of microscopic images of the same material (often without cells, just background structure) but without labels.  My idea was to label them automatically with pseudo classes,  create a new model and use this model to extract features for the 30000 images of interest.  Would this make sense (the microscopic images are much more related then cats and dogs, even they do not contain the two goal classes) and how could I put them into pseudo classes (and how many)?

Or is this idea totally dumb?

Thanks, 
Stefanie

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to say without seeing the data but my instincts would say that (a) you're probably doing something wrong if fine-tuning actually worsen your accuracies. (b) if you could promise that the material inside the cells is always the same one, you could do some sort of transfer learning and result to material detection, you could also combine this with a cell classifier and by doing so you'll get your problem solved.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am wondering what I am doing wrong( I am new to ML). The objects in the cells can differ quite a lot, that's the problem. First I tried to create an own model with the 30.000 labeled images and I got an accuracy of about 80%. If I extract features from the imagnet model and use a classifier, I reach about 85% accuracy. Here is an example of the cells, first two are with object, the other two without: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773369/object-detection-in-images-hog